# Implement a RadioButtonPreference in Android

Tags: android, preferences

How can you implement a `RadioButtonPreference` in android? Just like the `CheckBoxPreference`.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `ListPreference`. You need to have more than one radio button for it to be meaningful (otherwise, it would just be a checkbox).

If, for some reason, you do not want to use a `ListPreference`, grab the source code to `CheckBoxPreference` from the Android open source tree and roll your own Preference implementation. You should then be able to list your custom implementation in preference XML using the namespace (e.g., com.foo.`RadioButtonPreference`).

Comment: You can't have a summary (description) below each entry in the ListPreference, can you? So a RadioButtonPreference would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class extending from `CheckBoxPreference` like this:

```
public class RadioButtonPreference extends CheckBoxPreference {

    public RadioButtonPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_widget_radiobutton);
    }

    public RadioButtonPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_widget_radiobutton);
    }

    public RadioButtonPreference(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        if (this.isChecked()) {
            return;
        }
        super.onClick();
    }
}
```

Then create a `preference_widget_radiobutton.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout used by CheckBoxPreference for the checkbox style. This is inflated
     inside android.R.layout.preference. -->
<RadioButton android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:clickable="false"
             android:focusable="false"/>
```